# Select out of nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, combinatorics

I have a nested list:

```
{{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5, 6}}}
```

and would like to select only those lists out of it with two items in it:

```
{{{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}
```

How could this be achieved?

Comment: `Select[lst, Length@# == 2 &]` (see [Select](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html))

Comment: `Cases[lst,{_,_}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Input

```
data = {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5, 6}}};

Select[data, Length @ # == 2 &]
```

### Output

```
{{{1}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}}
```

Comment: thanks! very helpful

Comment: You are welcome :)